# Detect spambot on ubuntu 12 TLS

Tags: ubuntu, spam-prevention, postfix

Recently I discovered in my mail log that there is an enormous amount of spam being sent from my home server. I am running no websites, just zpanel. I closed down all the ports and am monitoring the `mail.log` file.

Entries look like this:

```
Jul 26 13:47:37 icarus postfix/smtp[19418]: EE28911C345A: to=<juliegarwood@juliegarwood.com>, relay=none, delay=29791, delays=29761/0.07/31/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to inbound.juliegarwood.com.netsolmail.net[206.188.198.64]:25: Connection timed out)
Jul 26 13:47:37 icarus postfix/smtp[19438]: connect to mx2.comcast.net[76.96.40.147]:25: Connection timed out
Jul 26 13:47:37 icarus postfix/smtp[19438]: connect to mx1.comcast.net[2001:558:fe14:70::22]:25: Network is unreachable
Jul 26 13:47:37 icarus postfix/smtp[19438]: connect to mx2.comcast.net[2001:558:fe2d:70::22]:25: Network is unreachable
Jul 26 13:47:37 icarus postfix/smtp[19423]: connect to extmail.bigpond.com[61.9.189.122]:25: Connection timed out
Jul 26 13:47:37 icarus postfix/smtp[19430]: connect to extmail.bigpond.com[61.9.168.122]:25: Connection timed out
Jul 26 13:47:39 icarus postfix/smtp[19420]: connect to mail.manhattan.k12.ks.us[12.167.72.199]:25: Connection timed out
Jul 26 13:47:40 icarus postfix/smtp[19420]: ECD7711C3348: to=<lindasc@manhattan.k12.ks.us>, relay=none, delay=34075, delays=34042/0.08/33/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.manhattan.k12.ks.us[12.167.72.199]:25: Connection timed out)
```

What are some ways to track down the cause of this?

Comment: Closed down what ports?   What does `sudo tcpdump port 25` give you (you may need to install this), and `sudo netstat -pant | grep 25`

Comment: @Paul `tcpdump` is listening but nothing is happening since I closed down most of the ports in iptables. netstat doesn't show anything on port 25 but there are a a fair amount of python instances: `tcp        1      0 192.168.1.125:57535     194.71.107.17:80        CLOSE_WAIT  4326/python
`

Comment: If the source is on the server itself, then `tcpdump -i lo port 25` should show it.  It may be that you have stuff left in your postfix queue, and postfix is trying to retry, or deliver underliverable notes.

Comment: @Paul I reconfigured my firewall which, for now, doesn't send out strange spam mails. However I do randomly get email to `root@icarus.ledi****.com`. `icarus` was set as reverse DNS but I removed that entry from my DNS zone over at the registrar a couple of days ago. These emails appear in bursts in the `mail.log`